# xml binding for ComboBox does not recognize SelectedItem

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I bind a XML document in a WPF window. The xml doc looks like this:

```
<root>
  <common>
    ... more stuff
    <logSeverityLevel>Debug</logSeverityLevel>
    ...
  </common>
  <collections>
    <logSeverityLevels>
      <logSeverityLevel>Debug</logSeverityLevel>
      <logSeverityLevel>Info</logSeverityLevel>
      <logSeverityLevel>Trace</logSeverityLevel>
      <logSeverityLevel>Error</logSeverityLevel>
      <logSeverityLevel>Fatal</logSeverityLevel>
    </logSeverityLevels>
  </collections>
</root>
```

And the the bindings:

```
<WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding XPath=/root/common}">

    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Log Severity Level : " />
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=logSeverityLevel}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/root/collections/logSeverityLevels/*}" />
    </DockPanel>
</WrapPanel>
```

Now when I run the program, I can see that the `ComboBox` is getting populated with the possible items. But it does not set `Debug` as the selected value. What to do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedValuePath="@logSeverityLevel"
          DisplayMemberPath="@logSeverityLevel" ... />
```

This is my example:

`XAML`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" XPath="Response/Contact">
        <x:XData>
            <Response xmlns="">
                <Contact Name="Bart" />
                <Contact Name="Eric" />
            </Response>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedValuePath="@Name"
          DisplayMemberPath="@Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}}"
          Width="100" Height="30"               
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

`Code behind`

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Without `SelectedValuePath` SelectedValue will be is empty.